# Django - Set a value before save

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a wallet at the moment the user signs up, but when the user fills out the form he is not redirected to the home, so little is persisted in the bank and get an error

Can someone help me fix this error?

```
Models.py
===============================================

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    key_simple = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    key_secret = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True)
    wallet = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        client = Client('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        data_account = client.create_account(name= 'Wallet of %s' % user.name)
        profile.walletid = data_account['id']
        data_address = client.create_address(data_account['id'])

        wallet_address_id = data_address['id']
        profile.wallet = data_address['address']
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: what does your description even mean ? What is the issue you are facing? what is the expected behavior ?

Comment: The data is not being persisted in the database and is not displaying error

Comment: your description is really incomplete....but from what I can see you are not saving your client after instantiating it and also I dont see any redirect....another thing is that signals are not very reliable, instead override your save method